# Can I do anything to improve the damage done by the demon summoned by my follower's Maximus?

Tags: diablo-iii

My enchantress uses the legendary two-handed sword Maximus, which quite frequently summons a large demon to fight with us.

It's quite a handy proc, but I'd like to know if there's any way I can make it more effective.

My enchantress' damage is quite low now, as I haven't really put much effort into gearing her (mostly I've added magic find gear) since she's primarily used for the attack speed buff.

Is the damage done by the demon in any way influenced by the gear my follower is using?  Is there any difference in the damage done by the demon if a player is wielding the weapon, instead of the enchantress?

Comment: I like this question and am curious to see if anyone has an answer.  On a related note, I am also curious if anyone has equipped the sword to themselves and their follower and gotten 2 demons at one time.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey I'm almost certain you can get 2 demons this way.  I'm 90% positive I have 2 of these swords (on enchantress followers with 2 different characters), so I'll try to test that out for you tonight.

Comment: I thought that the demon does a fixed damage (~35k) no matter what?  I could be wrong since I've never tested it though.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey I can verify that you can have 2 demons at one time by giving a Maximus to the enchantress, and using one yourself.

Comment: Is the demon any good?

Comment: @VaelVictus Like most summoned creatures, the demon seems pretty good as a distraction, keeping enemies occupied.  He's extremely durable, to the point where I don't know if he *can* be killed, and instead simply lasts for a fixed duration. I've really only used him on MP7, so its hard to know if the damage would be significant at lower levels (which is part of why I asked this question).

Answer (score 1):

The demon summoned by Maximus does a maximum damage of ~35k, it doesn't matter what stats you add to the enchantress, it's just a fixed DMG value.

It's a fantastic tool to use against chain enchantments though.

Comment: The Demonic Slave will fight for 15 seconds or until he is killed. He is pretty durable but arcane damage seems to be his Achilles' Heel. The fire chain deals 1,000 - 2,000 damage every .3 seconds and can critical hit. The demon itself deals 36k damage a swing on average and doesn't crit. As @Beofett indicated, it's possible to have three demon slaves fighting for you at one time.